# a js code works on firefox but not on chrome opera and edge

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cross-browser

This js code give a class to an element when it's visible to add animations. It works on mozilla, he gives the class to the element when it's visible but when I test on chrome and other web browser based on chromium it doesn't work. I've added jquery using the meta tag (for proof, it works under firefox)

```js
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
  var $elem = $(elem);

  // Get the scroll position of the page.
  var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
  var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

  // Get the position of the element on the page.
  var elemTop = Math.round($elem.offset().top);
  var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

  return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

function checkAnimation() {
  for (el = 1; el < (document.getElementsByClassName('partner').length + 1); el++) {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.partner:nth-child(' + el + ')');
    console.log(el);
    console.log(elem);

    if (isElementInViewport(elem)) {
      // Start the animation
      elem.classList.add('visible');
    }
  }
  el = 1
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function() {
  checkAnimation();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://dev2020.theelderguardian.fr/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://dev2020.theelderguardian.fr/partner.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="partner_1" class="partner">
                <figure class="partner_logo"><img class="logo" src="resources/assets/logos/partner_1.png"></figure>
                <div class="partner_desc">
                    <h3>Partner</h3>
                    <p>A great partner</p>
                    <div class="social">
            <div class="website"><a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-2x" style="color:#3c88c2;"></i></a></div>
            <div class="discord"><a href="discord.gg'" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><i class="fab fa-discord fa-2x" style="color:#7289DA;"></i></a></div>
            <div class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/partner" title="@partner" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x" style="color:#1da1f2;"></i></a></div>
            <div class="youtube"><a href="youtu.be" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-2x" style="color:#ff0000;"></i></a></div>
            <div class="instagram"><a href="https://instagram.com/partner" title="@partner" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-2x" style="color:#e1306c;"></i></a></div>
            <div class="other_link"><a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><img src="https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=example.com"></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why not use jQuery everywhere. jQuery consolidates stuff that may be different on various browsers

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML

Comment: I have the impression that the problem came from jquery, in the debugger the error is at the "querySelectorAll"

Comment: and it's strange that the code works on firefox but no on chrome-based browser

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've just tested another code and this time that works on all browsers

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    for (el = 1; el < (document.getElementsByClassName('partner').length + 1); el++) {
        var elem = document.querySelector('.partner:nth-child(' + el + ')');
        console.log(el);
        console.log(elem);

        console.log("invisible: ", isElementInViewport(elem));

        if (isElementInViewport(elem)) {
            elem.classList.add("visible");
        }
    }
});

function isElementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <=
          (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}
```